# debootstrap through authenticated proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, passwords

I am to install debian on my PC by 'from other linux' method and I run into problem with debootsrapt not being able to go through our proxy. As I understand the debootstrap doesnt have config file neither takes arguments on command line (relating to proxy), so I set following two environment variables:

```
ftp_proxy=http://myname:mypasswd@proxy.bla.bla.com:4128
http_proxy=http://myname:mypasswd@proxy.bla.bla.com:4128
```

Still I am getting:

```
# /usr/sbin/debootstrap --arch i386 wheezy /mnt/debinst http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release
```

the Release file can be get via browser, so it exists and so on...

I wonder if this can be done at all

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Well, I am to answer my question by myself.

With strace I found that debootstrap calls wget to fetch files from repositories. Obviously environment variables were somehow ignored but I edited /etc/wgetrc and put there all proxy related settings.

So it works.

BTW: debootstrap itself is just a script so maybe other workarounds would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the environment variables after setting them.

```
# ftp_proxy=http://myname:mypasswd@proxy.bla.bla.com:4128
# http_proxy=http://myname:mypasswd@proxy.bla.bla.com:4128
# export ftp_proxy http_proxy
# /usr/sbin/debootstrap --arch i386 wheezy /mnt/debinst http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian
```

Also, if you try to set them from a user shell and then use sudo to run debootstrap, those variables may not pass through so it's better to set them after getting to a root shell.

Comment: I tied this, and it did not work... unless I did some stupid error. And I can not re-test it now...

Comment: This didn't work for me either, so downvoting. @penguin359: please consider removing this answer unless you are really sure that it can work, at least in some cases.

Comment: Works for me.  Beware that if you use `sudo` to run the debootstrap command, your environment variables will probably not be passed along to the command.  For that to work, you explicitly need to tell sudo that you want to keep the env.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334303/failed-getting-release-file-while-running-debootstrap-with-sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try changing APT proxy things :

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy 
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy:4128";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxy:4128";
```